# Unpacking str dict value into datetime attribute of an object in a nice way

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a pydantic class like

```
class MyClass(BaseModel):
    base: str
    success: bool
    date: datetime
```

I also have a dict like

```
dict = {
    "base": "abc",
    "success": True,
    "date": "2023-04-30"
}
```

So I want to do something like obj = MyClass(**dict) but also convert str "date" from dict into datetime "date" of the obj automatically

How to do that in a clean and nice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/) to transform the value before it gets assigned to the `date` field. In the follow code will transform the date into a format supported by Pydantic:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from datetime import datetime

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    base: str
    success: bool
    date: datetime

    @validator('date', pre=True)
    def validate_date(cls, v):
        return f'{v}T00:00'


example = MyClass(**{
    "base": "abc",
    "success": True,
    "date": "2023-04-30"
})

print(example)
```

Running the above code will output:

```
base='abc' success=True date=datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 30, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Brilliant, ty! Missed the fact that validator can also transform a value